# How to query column data from table using sqlite and C#?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I used DB Browser to create a database called `Users.db` and then I manually created a table called `Users` in that database and created some fields that I might need to query from C# code. I am using the library SQLite to do this. How do I query data from the email column of the users table, here is what I tried to get the password data using email as a query parameter?

```
try
{
  SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("users.db");
  //get the email entered into the text box by the user
  string email = textBox1.Text;
  //define the command text to run on the table
  string query = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE email=" + email;
  //define a new SQLiteCommand
  SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(conn);
  //modify the query text of the command object
  command.CommandText = query;
  //how do I extract data from the returned row using command.executequery?
  var data = command.ExecuteQuery<TableMapping>();
  if (data != null)
     {
     //fetch the rows, except that SQLite throws an exception that I should not use TableMapping to query data
     }


}catch(SQLiteException exc){
  Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
}
```

Comment: Do not use string concatenation to create an SQL command. Use parameterized statements. See [why it's a bad idea and how to fix it](//bobby-tables.com).

Comment: You've shown your setup code, but can you show us your attempt at _using_ `command.ExecuteQuery`? There are plenty of resources on the internet to instruct you on using Sqlite in C#. What actual problem are you having?

Comment: I had used `TableMapping` to query data but SQLite said I cannot use that to query, editing

Comment: It looks like your attempt is simply incomplete.  What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?  Did you look up any [documentation or examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite) of how to use SQLite in C# and try anything at all?

Comment: You've updated the question... Now what specifically is the problem?  What is `TableMapping`?  What is the exact error message and which exact line of code produces that error?

Comment: I have no idea how to use the methods in the command object to get the data using the query, I tried looking online but only found implementations for Microsoft.Data.SQLite and others like C# sqlite but could not find implementations for this library as the command object has no `reader` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of issues here:

- `TableMapping` is not relevant here unless you want a custom mapping to a class. And for that you would not use `ExecuteQuery<TableMapping>`
- You just want `ExecuteQuery<string>` which will return a `List<string>`.
- Assuming the `email` is unique, you can just use `ExecuteScalar` which returns a single value.
- You need to parameterize your query, do not inject data into the query.
- You need `using` blocks to dispose the connection and command.
- You probably shouldn't be storing plain-text passwords anyway, but I'll leave you to think about that

```cs
try
{
    string email = textBox1.Text;
    const string query = @"
SELECT password
FROM users
WHERE email = @email;
";
    using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection("users.db"))
    using (var command = new SQLiteCommand(query, conn))
    {
        command.Bind("@email", email);
        var data = command.ExecuteScalar<string>();
        if (data != null)
        {
          // do something with it
        }
    }
}
catch(SQLiteException exc)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
}
```

Comment: Its returning a white space with no data , the email is correct though

Comment: I debugged your code, it needs the following as a query `SELECT password FROM users WHERE email='@email'`. The argument after the equals operator needs single quotes

Comment: That's if you want to look for the literal text `'@email'`, but if you are using bind-parameters then no it doesn't go in quotes

Comment: Your right I forgot the bind command code, Thanks for this answer